# IPhone over Android and vice versa

Tags: iphone, android

I develop applications on both **IPhone** and **Android**. As a part of my organization's *Technical Session* program I have myself delivering the next session on **iPhone or Android**. Getting the session made me start comparing both technologies, which believe me, is really a tough job. As a programmer in both technologies I often think how will the *Application* seem to be if I used the other one. Which further makes me list out pros and cons of both.

**Android ahead of iPhone**:

There are couple of factors where **Android** steps ahead of **iPhone**.

- Multiple apps at same time
- Information visible on home screen
- Better notifications
- Hardware flexibility

**iPhone ahead of Android**:

Following are the factors:

- UI Smoothness and Consistency
- Language support
- Accessibility options
- Battery life
- Resource efficiency
- Hardware quality
- Better App Store

However, as a programmer, I want my session to be more of *technical* rather than a being a general overview of both technologies. For which I need some help. For instance **Android's** memory management is way ahead of that of **iPhone's**. On the other hand **IPhone's** *UI* has no comparison at all.
What more (technical) points can I include in my session? Also, kindly correct me if I am wrong somewhere above.

Comment: I feel the memory management of android is not better than that of iOS, it's just different. If executed correctly the memory management of the iPhone can be just as effective. The biggest difference is in Android's automatic garbage collection. In iOS you have to do such things manually.

Comment: I think android biggest advantage it that it is open source and UI of android quite close to Iphone UI and it is getting better and better . So there is no doubt that Android will be the leading OS in future.

Comment: iPhone UI is uniform on every device. Android, on the other hand, is expected to be used on a broad array of devices that have different types of keyboards, different screen sizes and different customized features. Thus, developers for Android devices might have to make different tweaks in their designs for different devices.

Comment: Programming environment and languages. I know there are different oppinions out there what to prefer but you should consider it within your session. For example a far more better support of agile software development (refactoring) in Eclipse vs. better GUI design tools in XCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the UI goes.  I'm interested (as a programmer) to understand why exactly you consider iOS to be superior because in android the layouts that can be used are ever expanding and can be customized from the ground up where as in iPhone if you step outside of Apples box you get booted from the app store.